# Minecraft command too long

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I found a helicopter command I want to use in mc 1.9 but it's too long for a command block. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works the other way around: commands can be too long for the chat window, but not a command block

Answer (score 3):

One command cannot be to long for a command block.  It is possible that two or more commands are needed for what you are trying to accomplish.

Another possibility is you are trying to type it in the chat by just pressing `T` for talk.  commands in chat are restricted to a certain length and therefor cannot run all commands through the chat if to long.

Try giving yourself a command block by typing `/give <name> minecraft:command_block`  then copy and paste the command you want to run.

Comment: Nope. You can combine multiple commands into one by nesting the creation of command blocks.

Comment: True, but if he is watching a video that requires two or more commands then I doubt he can combine them with his knowledge.  And he wouldn't really necessarily need to.

Answer (score 1):

According to the minecraft Wiki, the text limit for commands in a command block is 32,500 characters. One thing you could do is have one `/summon` command block, with one or two additional `/entitydata` command blocks to finish the command.

Answer (score 0):

In 1.9 they shortened the length of command lines in command blocks.
The reason the command is too long is probably because it was made for 1.8.
If you found it through youtube I recommend you go back and watch the video again to see the version of minecraft it was made for. I also recommend that in the future (if this was the problem of course) you should not use 1.8 one command block creations in 1.9. This is due to the fact that command layouts were dramatically changed, for example tellraw, title, and playsound.